# How to extend a binary tree node without using an interface?

Tags: go, inheritance, embedding

```
type struct Node {
  x Data
  l *Node
  r *Node
}
```

Given the struct above, I am working on various implementations of binary search trees, all within the same package so that they can share internals without a public interface. However, some trees require a *rank* field as part of their node, which I would like to create as an extension of the base struct. I do not want the trees that do *not* require a rank field to allocate a node with a rank field.

```
type struct RankedNode {
  Node
  z rank
}
```

At first, this seems correct and communicates clear intent to me. However, this does not work because the internal `l` and `r` fields are of type `Node`, breaking code like this:

```
func (p *RankedNode) heapify() *RankedNode {
    // ...
    p.l.heapify()
    p.r.heapify()
}
```

Of course, `p.l` and `p.r` are of type `Node`, so `heapify` is not defined. We can make the assumption that any node can only be linked to nodes of the exact same type.

**Q:** Is a `Node` interface and type assertions the only way to achieve this without generics?

```
func (p *RankedNode) heapify() *RankedNode {
    // ...
    p.L().(*RankedNode).heapify() 
    p.R().(*RankedNode).heapify() // :(
}
```

Comment: The cynic in me says that you'll need to wait for generics for this to work in a clean manner.

Comment: Any reason to not give all nodes the `rank` field, but have a special value (maybe the zero value) to indicate that the rank is not used?  Then within methods you can switch on this value to do one behavior or another.

Comment: That is what I am doing currently, but my project involves benchmarking bytes allocated across many node copies, so I would really like to avoid that full word per node.

Comment: @rtheunissen it will be more space efficient overall than using interfaces, as interface is a 2 word data type